# How can I paste into Selenium WebDriver using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to paste from a clipboard using JavaScript on a page when I click on my element

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cell-O5vYiZt0g3xu"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]')
```

so What code can I put here?

```
driver.execute_script(wich_javascript_code)
```

Comment: Why you're not key chaining `ctr+v`?

Comment: This element I have does not have the send_keys () feature,But if you mean something else, I'll be happy for you to explain more

Comment: I tried this method but got no answer
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.META).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.META).perform()

Comment: Try `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')`

Comment: This element I have does not have the send_keys () feature